# Test an object is a subclass of the type of another instance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-3.4

I have this code:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a

class Sub(Item):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.b=b
        Item.__init__(self,a)

class SubSub(Sub):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
       self.c=c
       Sub.__init__(self,a,b)

obj1=Item(1)
obj2=Sub(1,2)
obj3=SubSub(1,2,3)
```

Now I want to check if `obj2` and `obj3` are instances of classes that are subclasses of `obj1` as well as simply subclasses of of `Item`.

Here is what I understand, I know that I can use the `isinstance()` to find if `obj2` is `Sub`. and I know that I can use `issubclass(Sub, Item)`. But let's say I didn't know what class `obj2` was.

I tried using `issubclass(type(obj2),Item)` but that doesn't work, because `type()` returns a separate object that I don't really understand the workings of. And this is just one problem, although I figure that the answer to this question will help me solve some of the other problems that I am having.

Also I have tried using some of the special attributes to do this such as `__class__` but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You'd need to extract the type of `obj` with the `type()` function:

```
isinstance(obj2, type(obj1))
```

Note that the *second* argument is the class, the first is the instance to test. `type()` is returning the actual class object here, not any *separate object*.

`issubclass()` works just fine for your usecase:

```
issubclass(type(obj2), Item)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Item:
...     def __init__(self,a):
...         self.a=a
... 
>>> class Sub(Item):
...     def __init__(self,a,b):
...         self.b=b
...         Item.__init__(self,a)
... 
>>> class SubSub(Sub):
...     def __init__(self,a,b,c):
...        self.c=c
...        Sub.__init__(self,a,b)
... 
>>> obj1=Item(1)
>>> obj2=Sub(1,2)
>>> obj3=SubSub(1,2,3)
>>> isinstance(obj2, type(obj1))
True
>>> issubclass(type(obj2), Item)
True
```

Note that if you re-defined the classes here, existing instances will *not* be updated to point to the new class objects. If `type(obj2)` doesn't work for you, then that means that the class used to produce it is not the same you are testing with now.

You can test if this the case by testing your assumptions; validate that the classes and instances are still in sync, for example:

```
>>> type(obj1) is Item
True
>>> type(obj2) is Sub
True
>>> type(obj3) is SubSub
True
```

Comment: Okay, that doesn't work. What exactly does the type() function return, as I understand it returns a separate object that I don't think can be used in this setting.

Comment: @A-P: Either you got some objects muddled up (importing vs local definitions maybe?) but `type()` does **not** produce a separate object. If it does then *you didn't create that instance from the class you are testing with*.

Comment: @A-P: If you re-defined the classes but didn't recreate the instances, then those instances will still be referring to the *old* class definitions. It sounds like that is the case for you here.

Comment: Okay yeah, I think it was some weird definition problems I was having because once I reset the shell and put everything in again it worked.

Comment: @selftaught91: that doesn't tell me much, I can't help you if you don't tell me what you tried and what happened instead.